# python hangman solver

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a program that read a csv file that contain 100 rows that look like:

```
1;S****L;SCHOOL
2;*A*G*A*;HANGMAN
```

then try to guess the letters like in a hangman game. My scope is to count every right and wrong letters and then sum them up. The code works fine, I get around 1670 right + wrong attempts to guess the letters. My approach was to create a dictionary in which I store all the letters from the alphabet and read every words from the file then sum every appearance of a letter and store them in the dictionary. Somethin like

```
{
   "A" : 30,
   "B" : 40
}
```

Then I sort the dict based on every letter occurrence and first try to guess the letter with the most apparace.

My question. Is something that I can improve in order to get a smaller number of attempts?

```
import csv

INPUT_FILE = "words.csv"


def oppenFile():        # function to read the file
    with open(INPUT_FILE, "r", encoding="utf-8") as words:
        reader = list(csv.reader(words, delimiter=";"))
        return reader


def letterCount():      # function that count every the letter in the file and return a dict: {A : 2}
    letters = dict.fromkeys("QWERTYUIOPĂÎASDFGHJKLȘȚÂZXCVBNM", 0)
    words = oppenFile()
    for w in range(len(words)):
        for l in list(words[w][2]):
            if l not in list(words[w][1]):
                letters[l] += 1
    return letters


def checkLetters(word, wholeWord, letters):     # function that solve a word return the number of right + wrong attempts
    attempts = 0
    for letter, key in letters.items():
        if letter in wholeWord and letter not in word:
            attempts += 1
            index = [i for i, lit in enumerate(wholeWord) if lit == letter]
            letters[letter] -= len(index)
            for j in range(len(index)):
                word = word[:index[j]] + letter + word[(index[j] + 1):]

        elif '*' not in word:
            break
        else:
            attempts += 1
    return attempts


def hangman():
    words = oppenFile()
    numberOfAttempts = 0
    letters = letterCount()

    for i in range(len(words)):
        letters = dict(sorted(letters.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)) # sort the dict

        numberOfAttempts += checkLetters(words[i][1], words[i][2], letters)

    print(f"{numberOfAttempts} right + wrong attempts")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    hangman()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to Code Review!

### PEP-8

In python, it is common (and recommended) to follow the PEP-8 style guide for writing clean, maintainable and consistent code.

Functions and variables should be named in a `lower_snake_case`, classes as `UpperCamelCase`, and constants as `UPPER_SNAKE_CASE`.

### Type hinting

With newer python versions, you can make use of type hinting to give a brief overview of the type of variables and function parameters.

### Counting letters

Python provides an inbuilt `collections.Counter` for you to make use of.

### Comments

The comments don't really help here. Also, prefer writing docstring over comments for functions.

### Variable names

You open a file, and name its pointer as `words`, whereas the function is returning a list of words; called `reader`, which in turn is stored in a variable called `words`?

### Weird conversions

You generate a mapping of letters to their respective counts, as a dictionary (hash-map/table/lookup), then convert it to list of 2-valued tuple, sort that, and convert back to dictionary. Why? `dict` has \$ O(1) \$ lookup and sorting makes no sense in your case.

### Iteration with index

You use the following loop structure:

```
for i in range(len(words)):
```

where, `i` in itself is serving no purpose. Every occurrence of usage of `i` is of the form `words[i]`. You can just iterate over the values of `words` list itself:

```
for word in words:
```